# Display result of convolution in PyTorch

Tags: image-processing, pytorch, convolution

PyTorch newbie here. I wrote a script (code below) that performs the following operations: load an image, perform a 2D convolution operation and then display the output and the input.

At present I have the image below, which seems off. How can I plot the feature map correctly?

[image: ted]

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn as nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imageio
import sys

A = imageio.imread('LiT.png')
# Define how the convolution operation works
conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=3, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

image_d = torch.FloatTensor(np.asarray(A.reshape(1, 3, A.shape[0] , A.shape[1])))
fc = conv2(image_d)
fc1 = fc.permute(0, 2, 3, 1).reshape([516, 780, 3])

plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(A)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(fc1.data.numpy())

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is this line

```
image_d = torch.FloatTensor(np.asarray(A.reshape(1, 3, A.shape[0] , A.shape[1])))
```

You can't just reshape the image you need to transpose the channels. As a remark for the future, if you get a stripy result like you did it's most likely some permutation/transposition or reshaping operation that's not correct.

Other than that I also scaled the input image to `[0, 1]` to show it properly. Below is the working code:

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn as nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imageio
import sys

A = imageio.imread('LiT.png')
# Define how the convolution operation works
conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=3, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

# from [H, W, C] to [C, H, W]
transposed_image = A.transpose((2, 0, 1))
# add batch dim
transposed_image = np.expand_dims(transposed_image, 0)

image_d = torch.FloatTensor(transposed_image)
fc = conv2(image_d)
fc1 = fc.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)[0]
result = fc1.data.numpy()
max_ = np.max(result)
min_ = np.min(result)
result -= min_
result /= max_

plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(A)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(result)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the problem lies in how you are permuting channels position in the image by using reshape. Instead, [`'np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) or [`tensor.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.permute) should be used. Using torch for permutation:

```
image_d  = torch.FloatTensor(np.asarray(A)).unsqueeze(0).permute(0,3,1,2)
```

Or, if we want to handle the permutation part in numpy:

```
image_d = np.transpose(np.asarray(A), (2,0,1))
image_d = torch.FloatTensor(image_d).unsqueeze(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the issue I had ;-)